# Rails fixtures - defining a table name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures, testunit

At the minute all my fixtures have the same name as the table that they are intended for, because of a recent issue with rails it doesn't seem possible to have a fixture beginning with the word 'test'

Does anyone know of a way to have a different fixture name and then map it to the correct table?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20080731112616/http://www.missiondata.com/blog/uncategorized/80/rails-fixtures-with-models-using-set_table_name/) looks similar to what you want to do.

Comment: This blog post link is dead

Answer (score 4):

You can set the class of a given fixture manually like so:

```
class SomeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  set_fixture_class widgets: 'Module::ClassInAModule'
  fixtures :widgets # or fixtures :all if you’ve defined all the mappings required

  test 'widgets can be found' do
    assert Module::ClassInAModule.all.any?, 'there should be widgets'
  end

end
```

Depending on how your tests/test helpers are set up, you may want to move this call to a parent class or something.

Answer (score 2):

In your model set this keyword:

```
class Anywhere < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "singular_table"
end
```

OBS: (Rails >= 5)

Comment: It just takes care of everything.